# SQL query to compare time difference

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've used the code below to query and got the output shown. Now, I would like to query as describe below. How should I do it?

> Find code 2, check if code 1 comes after code 2 within the same ItemID. If yes, compare the time difference. If time difference is less than 10 seconds, display the two compared rows.

```
    SELECT [Date]
      ,[Code]
      ,[ItemId]
      ,[ItemName]
  FROM [dbo].[Log] as t
join Item as d
on t.ItemId = d.Id
  where ([Code] = 2 or [Code] = 1) and ([ItemId] > 97 and [ItemId] < 100)
  order by [ItemId], [Date]
```

Output from the above query

```
         Date           Code  ItemName  ItemID  
2017-01-06 11:00:49.000  2       B      98
2017-01-06 11:00:49.000  1       A      98
2017-01-06 11:00:55.000  2       B      98
2017-01-06 12:01:56.000  1       A      98
2017-01-06 12:02:37.000  2       B      98
2017-01-06 12:03:49.000  1       A      98
2017-01-06 12:05:44.000  2       B      98
2017-01-06 20:24:32.000  1       A      98
2017-01-06 20:24:55.000  2       B      98
2017-03-14 16:37:42.000  2       B      99
2017-03-14 17:40:24.000  1       A      99
2017-03-14 17:40:25.000  2       B      99
2017-03-14 21:28:46.000  1       A      99
2017-03-15 08:03:07.000  2       B      99
2017-03-15 10:43:00.000  1       A      99
2017-03-15 12:01:17.000  2       B      99
2017-03-15 14:18:19.000  2       B      99
```

Expected Result

```
         Date           Code  ItemName  ItemID  
2017-01-06 11:00:49.000  2       B      98
2017-01-06 11:00:49.000  1       A      98
```

Comment: yup, from the result.

Comment: The first record should be Code 2?

Comment: @McNets Added the expected result

Comment: @Djuka No. It can be 1 and sometimes record can have code 2 then code 2 again. So, I need to check whether code 1 comes after code 2.

Comment: In output for ItemID=98 you have 10+ records. It should only be 2 records?

Comment: @Djuka this is only a sample record. I'll make some changes to make it clear.

Comment: Is it like this: For ItemID=98 check 1st and 2nd record, then 3rd and 4th, then 5th and 6th and so on...

Comment: @Djuka yes. you are right.

Comment: You have some identity column in there, right?

Comment: @Djuka yes. you are right. there should be an identity column which I did not include here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table results ([Date] datetime, Code int, ItemName char(1), ItemID int);
> insert into results values
> ('2017-01-06 11:00:49',  2,       'B',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 11:00:49',  1,       'A',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 11:00:55',  2,       'B',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 12:01:56',  1,       'A',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 12:01:58',  1,       'A',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 12:02:37',  2,       'B',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 12:03:49',  1,       'A',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 12:05:44',  2,       'B',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 20:24:32',  1,       'A',      98),
> ('2017-01-06 20:24:55',  2,       'B',      98),
> ('2017-03-07 00:02:27',  1,       'A',      91),
> ('2017-03-07 00:02:27',  1,       'A',      58),
> ('2017-03-14 16:37:42',  2,       'B',      99),
> ('2017-03-14 17:40:24',  1,       'A',      99),
> ('2017-03-14 17:40:38',  2,       'B',      99),
> ('2017-03-14 21:28:46',  1,       'A',      99),
> ('2017-03-15 08:03:07',  2,       'B',      99),
> ('2017-03-15 10:43:00',  1,       'A',      99),
> ('2017-03-15 12:01:17',  2,       'B',      99),
> ('2017-03-15 14:18:19',  1,       'A',      99);
> ```

> ```
> --= set a reset point when ItemId changes, or there is no correlative (2,1) couples
> --= keep in mind this solution assumes that first Code must be 2
> --
> WITH SetReset AS
> (
>     SELECT [Date], Code, ItemName, ItemId,
>            CASE WHEN LAG([ItemId]) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY [Date]) IS NULL
>                      OR ([Code] = 2)
>                      OR ([Code] = COALESCE(LAG([Code]) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY [Date]), [Code]))
>                 THEN 1 END is_reset
>     FROM   results
>
> )
> --
> --= set groups according to reset points
> --
> , SetGroup AS
>    (
>         SELECT [Date], Code, ItemName, ItemId,
>                COUNT(is_reset) OVER (ORDER BY [ItemId], [Date]) grp
>         FROM   SetReset
>     )
>     --
>     --= calcs diff date for each group 
>     , CalcSeconds AS
>     (
>         SELECT [Date], Code, ItemName, ItemId,
>                DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp), MAX([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)) dif_sec,
>                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) num_items
>         FROM   SetGroup
>     )
>     --
>     --= selects those rows with 2 items by group and date diff less than 10 sec
>     SELECT [Date], Code, ItemName, ItemId
>     FROM   CalcSeconds
>     WHERE  dif_sec < 10 
>     AND    num_items = 2
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                | Code | ItemName | ItemId
> :------------------ | ---: | :------- | -----:
> 06/01/2017 11:00:49 |    2 | B        |     98
> 06/01/2017 11:00:49 |    1 | A        |     98
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=33e69cce561445da72196c479d57d782)*

Comment: The comparison has to be within the same ItemId. Therefore, 06/01/2017 20:24:55 | 2 | B | 98 should be eliminated as well. Also, ItemId 99 are still displaying those more than 10 seconds

Comment: Please, clarify your question, what rows should NOT be returned? Because `2017-01-06 20:24:55.000  2       B      98`  and  `2017-03-14 16:37:42.000  2       B      99`, the second has another ItemID

Comment: I'm very sorry. I did not explain it properly. Check my output and expected result. The comparison has to happen within the same ItemId.

Comment: when I use this query on my data, I realize that some of the data with different ItemId are compared.

Comment: If you can post the changes I'll take a look.

Comment: I've added some sample data. Kindly have a look. Thanks. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=04ad65a36de9c94dd4cfeeee0c3bd54f

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort.